# deleting a row in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-3.0

I had a problem with deleting a row in c# .im writing a program for sky-l program and im checking the first coloumn and then i will decide which row is smaller(the first coloumn is important) plz help me how to delete the row. this the code.

```
       for (int f = 0; f < i; f++)
        {
            sortedsky[f, 0] = sky[min, 0];
            sortedsky[f, 1] = sky[min, 1];
            sortedsky[f, 2] = sky[min, 2];
            //how to delete???

            for (y = 0; y < i-1; y++)

                min = 0;
            if (sky[y+1, 0] < sky[min, 0])
                min = y;

        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: 0, 1, 2 is an index of item in the array?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to remove items from a list, consider using a `List<T>` instead of an array.

Comment: ok but how to deal with jagged/multidimension arrays, there is nothing built in

Comment: @Oded: `array[,]`, List of arrays would be `IList<IList<T>>`

Comment: @sll - `IList<IList<T>>` can be used for jagged arrays. Like you say, there is nothing built in for multidimensional arrays (though they can also be emulated with `IList<IList<T>>`).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using a generic List (which manages an array internally)

You can get a plain array from a list:

```
 List<Sky> listofSky;

 listofSky.Add(sky1);    
 listofSky.Add(sky2);    
 listofSky.Add(sky3);    

 Sky[] arr = listofSky.ToArray();
```

List also has simple Remove methods.